Appium image comparison with multiple result
I'm trying to make a image comparison with appium images plugin. The thing is that I now that the partial image I'm checking with the actual device screenshot should have multiple coincidences. As far as I read the findImageOccurrence method has an inner method called getMultiple() which should return an List<OccurrenceMatchingResult> with all the coincidences if the OccurrenceMatchingOptions has the enableMultiple() flag activated.
My issue is that having my code like it follows
OccurrenceMatchingOptions options = new OccurrenceMatchingOptions().withEnabledVisualization().enableMultiple(); List<OccurrenceMatchingResult> result = driver.findImageOccurrence(fullImage, partialImage, options).getMultiple();
It always ends up returning an  class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') And I don't now how to fix it. I tried different ways to use it but it always ends up with the same error
My appium version is the 2.5.4
Any help will be grateful

After asking the same question in the Appium. It looks that this was an undetected bug of the java-client lib. Check the post here https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-image-comparison-with-multiple-result/42455

Don't add SOLVED to the title, instead answer your own question with what solved your issue.
